# ¿Por qué el bcrypt me da un valor distinto?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Tengo un formulario que recoge la contraseña de mi página y la encripta por medio de bcrypt, este formulario se encarga de hacer que el usuario que está activándolo quede inactivo. Para ello busca con una query propia de laravel, de Eloquent, en la base de datos. El parámetro de la base de datos y el que le entra son iguales, una nadería típica, ya sabeis '123456'; el problema es que el bcrypt que guardo en la base de datos es uno y el que busco en la query es otro. ¿Por qué pasa esto si estoy usando el mismo método?

El método usado es este: `bcrypt($request->get('password'))`

Los valores de el parámetro son:

```
$2y$10$Pi1Cm7ThIFHLAmO.mE7lmuE5odgU96j5z8kryJhC0Z2rqfrcEB2oa
```

en el método de laravel y

```
$2y$10$K8q0RD0VIb/7KDddroAB2eelHz3BvLADK3kJoKjtNPKsLhnlULU4K
```

en la base de datos.

Como veis son diferentes aunque uso la misma encriptación.

Comment: ¿En qué punto no te funciona exactamente la comparación?

Comment: En la query eloquent con la que actualizo el valor de "u_activo" que es el parámetro que me define si el usuario está borrado o no, más concretamente, este es el código del "delete" $editado=(User::where('u_cliente_id', $idCliente)
            ->where('password', bcrypt($request->get('password')))
            ->update(['u_activo'=>0]))?true:false;;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La razón es porque la función `bcrypt` de Laravel en realidad trabaja bajo un método de `Hash`, por lo cual cada vez que ingresas la misma cadena de texto el `Hash` es diferente sin importar que sea la misma cadena.

Usando esta función:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ejecutada 4 veces, me arroja los siguientes resultados:

- $2y$10$BR9hlUAWOtufhsX8nXwtxewjImnsbyyuy2qpPLSjKmvrho/FGy02W
- $2y$10$BEFNyTcNJeCpik8EK2WaXOtFnsARyLSpradcTTAcKFbGroqZMZECq
- $2y$10$cWeARQgfsyCjDKlFrkGUq.8xTeUDHapI3D8VLxpR1D7NkjOA4HNSC
- $2y$10$YIYW6DAEs6wX9cpO8s.7Y.sUBtUvRWSAsMbFdOTMF/Vgj2Olw2Cwq

---

Para poder comparar es necesario usar el Facade `Hash` que provee el mismo framework.

```
if (Hash::check('contraseñaSinHash', $contraseñaConHash))
{
    // Realizar operaciones si la contraseña es la misma.
}
```

---

Para más información:

- https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/hashing
- https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funci%C3%B3n_hash
- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33860/how-does-hashing-work

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió

Answer (score 3):

Complementando la otra respuesta, lo que tendrías que hacer es obtener primero el usuario (por su llave primaria), y luego verificar su contraseña, para posteriormente actualizarlo:

```
$usuario = User::find($idCliente);
$editado = false;

if ($usuario && Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
    $usuario->u_activo = 0;
    $usuario->save();

    $editado = true;
}
```

Podrías hacerlo al revés, pero creo que no tendría mucha coherencia.

Comment: Lo hice así, gracias. No se cómo se marcan dos respuestas correctas porque la tuya me sirvió también.

Comment: No se pueden marcar dos respuestas, normalmente marcas la que te sirvió más.